# How to play two youtube videos with play one and pause another. Similarly when I play other video the previous video would pause

Tags: youtube

Can anyone please tell me how to play and pause youtube videos? I mean to say when I pause one video it should hide and exactly at the same position another video should come . And when I pause this then again the previous video would come.Remeber - each time I toggle, the previous video must pause.
I am using You tube API and need to embed two videos over there.

I am having trouble resolving this ... please help...

Comment: Could you add the informations on what you have done till now.

Comment: YouTube api player > have "if" statement > on click, play selected , pause all others.